# Python "is" comparison fails on wxPython menuitem

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to display some menus.  I have a function that takes a menuitem argument.  I then get the menuitem's parent menu, and iterate through the parent's list of menuitems to find my original menuitem - I need this so I can append a new menu item after the one I'm given - the insert routine uses the integer position. So...

```
def SetMenu( self, menuSeparator ):
    menu = menuSeparator.GetMenu()
    for m in menu.GetMenuItems():
        print m
        print menuSeparator
        print id(m), id(menuSeparator)
        print m.GetText()
        if m is menuSeparator:
            print "Found MRU StartSeparator"
            break
```

My code doesn't find the original item.  When I run it, I get the following output (trimmed)...

```
<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x97387f8> >
<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x97387f8> >
157717676 157694924

<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x9738e58> >
<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x97387f8> >
157717292 157694924
_Redirect Output
```

The first block shows the debug for the item I am looking for, but it doesn't match.  The menuitems appear to point to the same underlying object, but is the pointer different?  How can I get is to work?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: You can clearly see that the `id` *of the python objects* is different, so `is` is working correctly. Did you try to use `==` instead? Maybe the `wx` library has implemented it so that python objects pointing to the same underlying C object are equal.

Comment: `wxMenuItems` have an internal id you can get with `m.GetId()`; perhaps you could compare those.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  == didn't work.  I ended up using GetId().  It was a little inconvenient because the menuitem was a separator, which by default assigns the id to -2 every separator.  I needed to use the Append() method instead of AppendSeparator().